# React table optimization problem(HTML,CSS)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am making a simple web page using React and I need a table on this page. The contents of the table are OK, but the table is not properly aligned. I do not see any problem in the code. How Can I Solve This?

[image: Table]

```
import React from 'react'

const StuffList = () => {
    return (
        <div className='list-group'>
            <table className="table table-hover table-danger"></table>
            <thead>
                <tr className="bg-primary">
                    <th scope="col">T.C</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Surname</th>
                    <th scope="col">City</th>
                    <th scope="col">Jobe</th>
                    <th scope="col">Salary</th>
                    <th scope="col">Hobbies</th>
                    <th scope="col">U.Graduate</th>
                    <th scope="col">Graduate</th>
                    <th scope="col">P.Graduate</th>
                    <th scope="col">Blood Group</th>
                    <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                    <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                    <th scope="col">Details</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>2826572</td>
                    <td>Mike</td>
                    <td>White</td>
                    <td>Kansas</td>
                    <td>Student</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>Parachute</td>
                    <td>no</td>
                    <td>no</td>
                    <td>no</td>
                    <td>ARH-</td>
                    <td><button className='btn btn-warning'>Update</button></td>
                    <td><button className='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button></td>
                    <td><button className='btn btn-info'>Details</button></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </div>
    )
}

export default StuffList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give the `<tr style={{width:"100%",padding:"8px"}}>` and for tds you can add

`<td style={{padding:"8px}}>`

if it didn't worked give the table and its parent div 100% width

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: you should reset css by adding html,body,#root{ width:100%; height:100% } to the index.css.